# copy and paste from sheet 1 to sheet 2 transpose based on subject and without replacing existing data

Tags: excel, vba

i used this script to copy and paste data. however i want to past based on header and the following row as there will be multiple data inputted

```
Sub copytosheet()

Range("B13:B23").Copy

Worksheets("Excel A&P").Range("B14:O14").PasteSpecial , Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

[image: sheet 1]

[image: Sheet 2]

a revised vba script which ables me to paste based on header similarities between sheet1 column A and sheet2 row 13. Then the data pasted moves to next row below as more people input the data

Comment: It's doable if you provide a mapping table. eg. `Created Date` is populated with B13.

Comment: If the source data will always be in the same order, you could just copy the cells one at a time. There doesn't seem to be anything in your code about finding the last row on your destination sheet, have you tried anything to find the last row? There are lots of posts related to that on this and other sites.

Comment: in Sheet 1, Column A and Column B are the mapping table. So in Sheet 2, Since date is pasted transpose, Row 13 if similar to Sheet 1 Column A, then the data from Column B should be inputted.